# Packages unmet when I try to install nginx

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, dependencies, package, passenger

when I try to run `sudo apt-get install nginx-full` I get this error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
nginx-full : Depends: nginx-extras (>= 1:1.10.1-8.5.0.30~trusty1) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: nginx-extras (< 1:1.10.1-8.5.0.30~trusty1.1~) but it is not going to be installed
```

so I run `apt-get install nginx-extras` and I get this error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
nginx-extras : Depends: perlapi-5.18.2 but it is not installable
               Depends: libperl5.18 (>= 5.18.2) but it is not installable
               Recommends: passenger (< 5.0.31) but 1:5.0.30-1~wheezy1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

How can I fix?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe ubuntu version error,try this command~

sudo sh -c 'echo deb https://oss-binaries.phusionpassenger.com/apt/passenger xenial main > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/passenger.list'

Answer (score 3):

For me, I have solved this problem by removing the added repository link. I have removed it from my ubuntu server digital ocean.

> sudo rm -rf /etc/apt/sources.list.d/passenger.list

Answer (score 1):

I also encountered the same issue while setting up for my application https://www.wiki11.com.

Please map to new apt repository in order to access the Phusion Passenger 4 libraries.

```
deb https://oss-binaries.phusionpassenger.com/apt/passenger/4 trusty main
```

And then run your command

```
sudo apt-get install nginx-extras
```